# unable to delete build completely

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have manually deleted a CI build that uses the MS Hosted ubuntu Agent as there was no Cancel option that was showing up. The elapsed time I think shows the build was deleted, but I see that the Hosted Agent continues to show that the build is in progress.

This is the first time I am running in to this situation. What is the best way to abort this build. I tried using the APIs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/update%20build?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) but that does not seem to help

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After investigation, there is a recently event of availability degradation of Azure DevOps, which affected these services and it has been resolved now.

If you want to know more information, please click here: https://status.dev.azure.com/_history.

Please check that your Cancel option is back to normal.

[image]

Comment: If the answer is helpful, would you please accept it as answer? Thank you very much.:-)